# How is the result produce in a recursion?

Tags: java, recursion

First Code: **a = 5**

```
    if (a==0)
        return 1;

    return a * xample(a-1);
```

My tracing:

5==0 FALSE
skip return 1
return 5 * xample(5-1)
so, a = 4

go back inside the method
4==0 FALSE
skip return 1
return 5 * xample(4-1)
so, a = 3

go back inside the method
3==0 FALSE
skip return 1
return 5 * xample(3-1)
so, a = 2

go back inside the method
2==0 FALSE
skip return 1
return 5 * xample(2-1)
so, a = 1

go back inside the method
1==0 FALSE
skip return 1
return 5 * xample(1-1)
so, a = 0

go back inside the method
0==0 TRUE
return 1

so last value is 1, how come the real last value is 120?

Second Code: **a = 5**

```
    if (a<1)
        return 1;
    else
        return a + xample(a/5);
```

how come the answer is 7?

Third Code: **a = 5**

```
    a--;
    if (a>0)
    {
        xample(a);
    }
    return a;
```

How come the answer is 4???

Comment: Fire up your debugger, single-step through the examples, watch the "call stack" display. That's ***by far*** the best way to see how this works. Textual descriptions tend to be very weak in comparison.

Comment: What part is unclear? Use a debugger to watch what happens when you run the code. If you don't have or know how to use a debugger, stop what you're doing and get one / learn the basics of using one. Using a debugger is a fundamental part of programming, including learning programming.

Comment: Wait: You're saying you're unwilling to take a few minutes to do the best thing you can do to understand recursion? Due respect, but that seems an odd approach to learning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the following code :

```
if (a==0)
    return 1;

return a * xample(a-1);
```

If a is 5 :

```
return 5 * xample (5 - 1) = 
       5 * 4 * xample (4 - 1) =
       5 * 4 * 3 * xample (3 - 1) =
       5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * xample (2 - 1) =
       5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 * xample (1 - 1) =
       5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 * 1 = 120
```

Comment: great!!!! i understand the process of the first code now.... so it only means that when the method is being called again the value of a will change!!! i thought it will remain to 5!!! great!! I gotta understand the other codes!!! thanks...

Comment: but wait...... why is it 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 * 1 ??? it should be 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 * 0..... because 1-1 is 0.....

Comment: @Rae `if (a==0) return 1;`

Comment: by the way, i dont understand how the third code works....
why does it ascends back until 4 when 1-1=0?

Comment: @Rae The last code ignores the output of the recursive call, so you can replace it with this equivalent code : `a--; return a;`

Comment: @Rae It calls `xample(a)`, but it doesn't do anything with the returned value. Therefore, as long as this recursive call doesn't cause an infinite recursion (which it doesn't, due to the combination of a-- and the condition `if a>0`), it may as well not be called at all.